# how to populate the /usr/lib/python-exec folder?

Tags: python

I am having issue on updating my linux distribution because the package manager for some reason is no longer installing the necessary files on /usr/lib/python-exec folder and I am not having progress on solving it by the default installation. So I want to know how I can populate that folder, the files I am needing are `/usr/lib/python-exec/python3.9/glib-genmarshal, /usr/lib/python-exec/python3.9/glib-mkenums, /usr/lib/python-exec/python3.9/gdbus-codegen, /usr/lib/python-exec/python3.9/dtrace and /usr/lib/python-exec/python3.9/gtkdoc-scan`. I could not find much information regarding python-exec, just that it stores python wrappers of binary programs.

my last attempt was installing exec-wrappers to build the wrappers on the mentioned folders, I made some progress but now I am getting errors about not finding python modules

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your on Gentoo Linux?
If so eselect-python is how I configure preferred/active Python
interpreters.
You can run a

```
eselect python list
```

Then

```
eselect python set [version]
```

eselect-python alters altering python-exec.conf.
You can also alter this file other ways
See also
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Python/python-exec

Comment: I have already tried it, but unfortunately it did not worked either

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

So far using exec-wrappers and uninstalling an ebuild I have made, conflicting with already existing python files from system solved my problem. I had files with the same name on /usr/bin and /usr/lib/python3.9, so python took the wrong files and could not find some expected variables